# php excel read returning weird characters

Tags: php, excel

I'm using this function to read rows from csv file.

```
    <?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

echo $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

And I'm getting this

```
    PK!|l˜l [Content_Types].xml ¢( Ì”]KÃ0†ïÿCÉ­4Ù&ˆÈº]øq©çˆÍé–&!'›Û¿÷4û@¤nzÓÐæœ÷}’4ïp¼jL¶„€ÚÙ‚õye`K§´ìmú”ß²£´Jg¡`k@6]^§k˜Q·Å‚Õ1ú;!°¬¡‘ÈK3•ŒôfÂËr.g ½Þ(`c[ 6>@%&f+ú¼!  `e÷›ÂÖ«`Ò{£K‰T­úæ’o8u¦¬µÇ+Â`¢Ó¡ùÙ`Û÷B[´‚l"C|– aˆ•.Ìß›óÃ"”®ªt   Ê•‹†v€£ Ö±1<¼‘Úî¸ø§bièŸ¤]_>‘cðO8®ÿˆ#Òÿ"=$IæÈ`\À3¯v#zÌ¹–Ôk”gøª}ˆƒîÑ$8”(Nß…]d´Ý¹'!QÃ>4º.ßÞ‘ÒètÃo·Ú¼S :¼EÊ×Ñ'ÿÿPK!µU0#õL_rels/.rels ¢( 
Œ’ÏNÃ0ÆïH¼CäûênH¡¥»LH»!TÀ$îµ£$@÷ö„‚JcÛÑöçÏ?[ÞîæiTb/NÃº(A±3b{×jx­ŸV b"giÇŽaWÝÞl_x¤”›b×û¨²‹‹º”ü#b4Oñìr¥‘0QÊahÑ“¨eÜ”å=†¿P-<ÕÁj{ª>ú<ù²·4Mox/æ}b—NŒ@ž;ËvåCf©ÏÛ¨šBËIƒóœÓÉû"cž&Ú\Oôÿ¶8q"K‰ÐHàó<ßŠs@ëë.Ÿh©ø½Î<â§„áMdøaÁÅT_ÿÿPK!Þ ý(Ôxl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels ¢( 
¼“ÏjÃ0Æïƒ½ƒÑ}q’ne”:½ŒA¯[÷&QâÐÄ6–ö'o?“Cº@É.¡ƒ$ü}?Ð§ýá§ïÄjU%)´¥«ZÛ(ø8½><ƒ Ö¶Ò³¨`@‚Cq·ÃNsüD¦õ$¢Š%†Ùï¤¤Ò`¯)qmœÔ.ôšcéuyÖ Êõ’ýãšöO    /îc)ÇwÚ‡œÝbñÿÿPK!«h&¨bqxl/workbook.xmlŒRËNÃ0¼#ñ–ï4©Ó·šTB€è!QÚ³‰7UÇŽl‡´ÏÆQKQ/œv×;ÏŒ³\+E¾Á:itJ‡ƒ˜Ð¹RïSú¹yy˜Qâ<×‚+£!¥'pt•Ýß-[c_Æh—ÒÒûzE./¡ân`jÐ¸)Œ­¸ÇÑî#W[àÂ•¾R‹ãITq©iÏ°°ÿá0E!sx2ySö=‰Å=Êw¥¬Í–…T°í^×o¼BÝGE‰âÎ?éA¤tŒ£iáÏmêÇF*ÜÎ“˜Ñ(»˜|·D@Áå7hïÌŽy±c“ÙE±•Ðºßº‘wRÓ¦t4ÃhOç)Á¡ ›¾L)›Nç¨©?{¹/=Ò'É8îØ£+ú ^*ÑÁÝGê_ª«k4€½]HlìZ;†4»BcAß7èä
ýuŽ’r®rŒª+AÄhÓ8h{w†ýK’
ÇcÌxLÚÞœHïÚÖûï]Å›*$A°>–›¸í…J%›•ŠôaËËACMÒÛÊˆ÷¼ÆJêŸ‰&Mœ;žÖ4BÎe—    tˆYÛ>c~4$”‡–
```

I have tried many other but getting the same output.
Is there any way I can get string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a zip file, not a csv file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a CSV file, it is a ZIP file (note the `PK` at the beginning).

Probably this is an xlsx file (excel in xml inside a zip package) that you either misnamed or that has the full name `test.csv.xlsx` but Windows is hiding your real extension (if you are on Windows).

Comment: I saved the file again in excel as csv and it works. I remembered before I saved it as xlsx and then renamed it as .csv, I think that was causing the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give lineseperator of your csv file like

```
$csvcontent = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,"\t");
```

where "\t" is your line seperator.and I think it is not an CSV file...either it is an Zipped file or like .xlsx extended file,First check it once